# For for "located outside the body"

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word for "located outside of the body." For instance, blood found outside of the body can be described using this word.

Thank you.

Comment: Extracorporeal, perhaps?

Comment: @Hot Licks: are you guessing or uncertain of what extracorporeal means?

Comment: @ealy - Have you looked it up?

Comment: @Hot Licks: in my opinion you are right, why you don't answer?

Comment: @ealy - I don't do answers -- too much work!

Comment: @Hot Licks: are you sure that using comments instead of answers is consistent with the rules of ESE?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65588/discussion-between-ealy-and-hot-licks).

Comment: Wouldn't it be obvious from context that any blood found outside the body is outside the body?

Comment: *in vitro* in some circumstances, but not usually the one you describe.

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you are looking at is extracorporeal, as suggested by Hot Licks

> http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/extracorporeal

*Something that is outside the body, such as extracorporeal circulation in which venous blood is diverted outside the body to a heart-lung machine and returned to the body through a femoral or other artery.*

Answer (score 1):

If "extracorporeal" (as suggested by @Hot Licks and @ealy) is not what you are looking for, you might like "extrasomatic," which is what came to my mind.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/extrasomatic

> *of, relating to, or being something that exists external to and distinct from the individual human being or the human body*